# customize the session message of liferay

Tags: liferay

I work with liferay 5.2 ,

Liferay display in case of inactivity this message

> warning,due to inactivity,your session has espired.please save any data you may have entered before refreshing

I want to customize this message , I want to display this message:

> Due to lack of use of the system will be closed

instead of default message,

and also I want to display this message in the middle of the page instead of top of the page.

so I think that I should modify the css of the div of this message in liferay

Answer (score 1):

You need create **hook** of **Language.properties** file and change the default value for below key

warning-your-session-has-expired=Warning! Due to inactivity, your session has expired. Please save any data you may have entered before refreshing the page.

so you can put like this

**warning-your-session-has-expired=Due to lack of use of the system will be closed.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you read the below link i think you will find your an answer:

[Liferay User Feedback - Success and Error Messages in Portlets](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/User+Feedback+-+Success+and+Error+Messages+in+Portlets)

Answer (score 0):

This Can help you [changing session out message in theme](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14420906)